# How composite png sequence onto zoompan?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following command that successfully creates a 10 second video from a single image.

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i /var/www/html/data/photos/$image.jpg -vf \"zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.12)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=240:s=hd1080:fps=24\" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 -s hd1080 -crf 20  /var/www/html/data/renders/$project_id/$scene.mp4
```

How would I go about compositing a PNG sequence on top of this clip. The PNG sequence would be named `0.png` --> `239.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [overlay filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 24 -i image.jpg -framerate 24 -i %03d.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v]zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0005,1.12)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=240:s=hd1080:fps=24[bg]; \
 [bg][1:v]overlay=10:10:shortest=1,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4
```

Consider zero-padding your file names from `1.png` to `001.png` so they are fed to the [image file demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) in the proper order.

Comment: this seems to work, but it has also introduced a slight 'jitter' to my zoompan-- where before it was very smooth. What could be causing this? A scaling issue of some sort?

Comment: @user1661677 I'll try to take a look tomorrow.

Comment: very much appreciated. Thank you for your help thus far.